# Guess the distribution for the precipitation and temperature over time

Tags: distributions, histogram, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, climate

I am studying the data obtained from 370 weather stations distributed worldwide. I have one measure of **minimum temperature** and **precipitations** per day from 1980 to 2012.

I have plotted the data, these are the histograms:

[image]

[image]

I would like to know the distributions asociated to these sets of measures, I am going to try the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but I need some distribution to run the test, since I don't recongnise them.

Comment: The bottom histogram is likely bimodal from the northern and southern hemispheres.

Comment: @Carl - presumably the hot peak may be nearer the tropics than the poles.

Comment: It seems surprising how narrow the precipitation graph is.  Have you averaged over time or location?

Comment: Looks gamma distribution like, which would not be shocking, rainfall is sometimes gamma distributed in the lit.

Comment: @Henry True, but that is more southern hemisphere in the winter, and more northern in the summer.

Comment: There are a lot more stations on the northern hemisphere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is run a Find Distribution routine like [FindDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html) in Mathematica. That would give you a better idea. The first distribution might be a gamma distribution, and the lower one may be a mixture distribution or it might be a U-shaped beta distribution, but, it is better to check against multiple actual models to find the best ones.